# Car audio system not putting out as much bass

Tags: audio

Hey so I recently big time upgraded my system from:
-Kenwood kfc1666s Speakers
-Boss r1100m mono sub
-Polk db+ subwoofer (375rms)

I upgraded to:
-2 JBL GTO929 6x5
-2 JBL GTO939 6x8
-Alpine S A32F (4 channel)
-Alpine S A60M (Monoblock)
-Kept the same Polk Sub
(Also have a Alpine PDR-M65 got a good price on used)

Both are using stock headunit in my Mazda 3 2013

The issue is that with the first setup I got much stronger bass from my sub ???

The Alpines should put out more if not better sounding bass I pretty sure. I'm running 4ohm with one sub.

I know it's something I'm forgetting to adjust or I didn't do but I anyone has any ideas I'd be happy to hear them

I'll add if it helps that I have a cheap LOC behind head unit. I have checked ground connection and power connect. Ground is in factory ground point in back I brushed paint off and all that. Power is circuit breaker inline and distribution blocks for both Power and ground.the wire is all ofc except the main power wire going from inline to distribution block. I'm going to test the amp with a multimeter tomorrow to see what's it's putting out.

I'm thinking it could be the head unit or stock amp interfering with it. Does anyone know if that is possible or if it even has a stock amp. This is NOT a Mazda with a bose system

Idk lol

Thank you

Comment: OK incase anyone reads this I figured out what was wrong I was using 1 4channel LOC spliced in behind my stock headunit. Qnd splitting the rear channels to rear speakers and sub ( I also tried splitting front and back and give rear too sub but same problem happened) so I ended up hooking 4 channel LOC straight to 4 channel amp and connecting mono via hi level inputs. And that worked much better. So I ordered a 2 channel LOC for the mono and ima put it next to the amp and run 9wire from headunit.

Comment: I had the problems I was having from splitting the front signal to my sub. And when I split the rear signal to my sub though?? Like I was have my channel just cut out completely like the front left and rear right just out qnd very little bass or all channels working and very lil bass??? I just still don't understand why